# Assembly x86 MASM, ReadString issue

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

```
.data

buffer              DWORD 30 DUP (0)

greetingTitle       BYTE    "Welcome to the Integer Accumulator by chris",0
greetingName        BYTE    "What is your name? ",0
userName            DWORD   ?
userGreeting        BYTE    "Hello there, ",0

.code
main PROC

; introduction

    ;prints title and asks for user name
    mov     EDX, OFFSET greetingTitle
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    mov     EDX, OFFSET greetingName
    call    WriteString

    mov     EDX, OFFSET buffer
    mov     ECX, SIZEOF buffer
    call    ReadString
    mov     userName, EAX

    mov     EDX, OFFSET userGreeting
    call    WriteString
    mov     EAX, OFFSET userName
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
```

output:

Welcome to the Integer Accumulator by chris
What is your name? chris
Hello there, Hello there,

Having trouble with readstring, it's printing out a second "Hello There", instead of "Chris". I've read my textbook over a couple times and it's just not clicking for me.

any help with an explanation would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: `ReadString` presumably put the name into `buffer` since that's what you passed. You should print that, not `userName` which likely contains the length (assuming `ReadString` returns that in `eax`).

Answer (score 0):

```
mov EDX, OFFSET buffer
mov ECX, SIZEOF buffer
call ReadString
```

your data is saved in buffer if you want to access

```
mov edx, offset buffer
call writestring
```

if you want it in eax register you should use a loop and pass 4 char in each loop by using rol.